# How to align FA-icon and text on a title bar?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I wanted to know how to align a fa-icon container to a text that I am using as a title bar.

Here the "ideal" outcome of how I would like to get it done. [Ideal look just an image][1]

Here is my code, that doesnt look like that:

```css
 */*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box}html{font-family:sans-serif;line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-overflow-style:scrollbar;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent}@-ms-viewport{width:device-width}article,aside,dialog,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section{display:block}body{margin:0;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";font-size:1rem;font-weight:400;line-height:1.5;color:#212529;text-align:left;background-color:#fff}[tabindex="-1"]:focus{outline:0!important}hr{box-sizing:content-box;height:0;overflow:visible}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:.5rem}p{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:1rem}abbr[data-original-title],abbr[title]{text-decoration:underline;-webkit-text-decoration:underline dotted;text-decoration:underline dotted;cursor:help;border-bottom:0}address{margin-bottom:1rem;font-style:normal;line-height:inherit}dl,ol,ul{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:1rem}ol ol,ol ul,ul ol,ul ul{margin-bottom:0}dt{font-weight:700}dd{margin-bottom:.5rem;margin-left:0}blockquote{margin:0 0 1rem}dfn{font-style:italic}b,strong{font-weight:bolder}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{position:relative;font-size:75%;line-height:0;vertical-align:baseline}sub{bottom:-.25em}sup{top:-.5em}a{color:#007bff;text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:objects}a:hover{color:#0056b3;text-decoration:underline}a:not([href]):not([tabindex]){color:inherit;text-decoration:none}a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):focus,a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):hover{color:inherit;text-decoration:none}a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):focus{outline:0}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}pre{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:1rem;overflow:auto;-ms-overflow-style:scrollbar}figure{margin:0 0 1rem}img{vertical-align:middle;border-style:none}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}[role=button],a,area,button,input:not([type=range]),label,select,summary,textarea{-ms-touch-action:manipulation;touch-action:manipulation}table{border-collapse:collapse}caption{padding-top:.75rem;padding-bottom:.75rem;color:#868e96;text-align:left;caption-side:bottom}th{text-align:inherit}label{display:inline-block;margin-bottom:.5rem}button{border-radius:0}button:focus{outline:1px dotted;outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{margin:0;font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit}button,input{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}[type=reset],[type=submit],button,html [type=button]{-webkit-appearance:button}[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner,[type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner,[type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner,button::-moz-focus-inner{padding:0;border-style:none}input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type=date],input[type=datetime-local],input[type=month],input[type=time]{-webkit-appearance:listbox}textarea{overflow:auto;resize:vertical}fieldset{min-width:0;padding:0;margin:0;border:0}legend{display:block;width:100%;max-width:100%;padding:0;margin-bottom:.5rem;font-size:1.5rem;line-height:inherit;color:inherit;white-space:normal}progress{vertical-align:baseline}[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}[type=search]{outline-offset:-2px;-webkit-appearance:none}[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}::-webkit-file-upload-button{font:inherit;-webkit-appearance:button}output{display:inline-block}summary{display:list-item}template{display:none}[hidden]{display:none!important}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
   <!-- falconer site v2 -->
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <title>Falconer Aviation - Licencia Piloto Privado de Avión</title>
      <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
      <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Custom Fonts -->
      <link href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <!-- Custom CSS -->
      <link href="../css/cursos.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <section id="services" class="services bg-primary text-white">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="section group">
               <div class="col span_1_of_2">
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
                     <div class="service-item">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col span_1_of_2">
                  <h5>
                     <p align="left"><strong>Licencia Piloto Privado de Avión</strong></p>
                  </h5>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- /.container -->
      </section>
      <div>

This is how it actually looks like:[Actual look][2]

Basically I just want the airplane icon on the left, and right next to it the text.

Any idea on how to align the fa-icon on the blue top bar?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXgLG.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfDsO.jpg

Edit: adding CSS used: 
bootstrap.min.css

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

cursos.css

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Stylish Portfolio (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/stylish-portfolio)
 * Copyright 2013-2017 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

/* Global Styles */

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.text-vertical-center {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text-vertical-center h1 {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Custom Button Styles */

.btn-dark {
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.btn-dark:hover, .btn-dark:focus, .btn-dark:active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.btn-light {
  color: #333;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.btn-light:hover, .btn-light:focus, .btn-light:active {
  color: #333;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}


/* Custom Horizontal Rule */

hr.small {
  max-width: 100px;
}


/* Side Menu */

#sidebar-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease 0s;
  transition: all .4s ease 0s;
  transform: translateX(250px);
  background: #222;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 55px;
  height: 55px;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

#menu-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#sidebar-wrapper.active {
  right: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease 0s;
  transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}

.toggle {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}


/* Header */

.header {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* About */

.about {
  padding: 50px 0;
}


/* Services */

.services {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.service-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}





/* Footer */

footer {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#to-top {
  font-size: 1em;
  position: fixed;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  display: none;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF TWO  */
.span_2_of_2 {
 width: 100%;
}
.span_1_of_2 {
 width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col { 
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span_2_of_2, .span_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
}
```

Comment: Could you also post your CSS?

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Its Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Do you want to align the font awesome text with the heading vertically?

Comment: @Tibs, yes sir.

Comment: @ALEZA Check my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your css, but here is some html&css I will give you that should work fine. You need to add it properly tho.

HTML:

```
<div id="topbar">
  <div class="barcol>
    <!--The fa icon here.-->
  </div>
  <div class="barcol>
    <div class="barcol-row">Some text</div>
    <div class="barcol-row">Some text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topbar {
  display: flex;
}
```

The rest of the styling is up to you. This is just the simple structure I made fast for you and I hope you understand it and it's fine for you. :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, It didnt work. (I added both html and css)

Comment: @ALEZA You must be putting it in wrong then I think.
Anyway I realized you're using bootstrap - I can't help you then, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Bootstrap 4, it uses flexible box layout module.
You can control column content alignments by using the `align-items` property.
NOTE: It will only work on flexi-box grid.

Check the fiddle I created.
https://jsfiddle.net/qdktejak/1/

For more `align-items` property values, see https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/ for reference.

Comment: looks great, is possible to have the text, without so much spacing next to the icon? (also, to use you code I just need to copy paste all the HTML and CSS?)

Comment: Yes you can but you must also add content to the right side so it would look balanced. The font size of the icon is too big. Practically no one would use an icon that big unless it is a button with a big purpose like call to actions.

Comment: thanks man, where should I edit the FAicon font size. Also, is there a way to reduce the margin to the left on the icon, I'd like to have aligned to the left, and the text right next to the icon.

Comment: For font awesome size adjustments, see http://fontawesome.io/examples/, or you can just edit the stylesheet of your site.

Comment: any hints on how to reduce the margins?